# IJCADのGcadApplicationを取得する方法について

Tags: .net, ijcad

IJCADで.NETアプリケーションを使っています。

初歩的な質問なのですが、起動しているIJCADGrxCAD.ApplicationServices.Application.GcadApplicationの取得方法をご教示ください。IJCAD APIのヘルプを読んでもよくわからなかったので。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

IJCAD APIのヘルプは確かにわかりづらいです。

IJCADのGrxCAD.Interop.dllを追加し、Interaction.GetObjectメソッドを呼び出すとIJCADのGcadApplicationを取得できます。